# Form button to add new table row and assign primary key

Tags: ms-access

On Mirosoft Access 2013 I have a form that requests the document number and revision from a user

i.e. "Enter Document Number", user enters Doc001

"Enter Revision Number", user enters 1

What I would like to do is add a "Create Record" button that when the user clicks it adds a new row to the "Documents" Table with a primary key that is a concatenation of Document Number and Revision.

So for the above for example the primary key on the new row would be "Doc001 Rev A"

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Store *DocumentNumber* and *RevisionNumber* in the table as separate fields and have an *Autonumber* as the primary key. Bind the form to this table.

To display the concatenated number, use this expression:

```
[DocumentNumber] + " Rev " + Chr(64 + Nz([RevisionNumber], 1))
```

Comment: Ok thank you. We have around 300-400 columns associated with that DocumentNumber split over two tables. If a user wants to update the revision of a document, e.g. rev A to rev B, would there be a way to add the document number and the new revision number (Rev B) to a new row across the two tables on button click? I'm guessing these would also need to have the same autonumber primary key?

Comment: The new version of the document will/should get a new Id (autonumber), the same DocumentNumber, and the next RevisionNumber.

Comment: It does on the “Documents” table, but we also have a “Documents2” table (there are over 300 columns assigned to that row split over two tables) that contains additional data that needs the row creating with the same info as well (doc number, Rev level and auto number primary key)

Comment: Then, I guess, you must create a new version (record) in that table also.

Comment: Is there a way to create the same record on two tables by clicking on the same button on a form?

Comment: Yes. Run an append query, for example.